# Are Overwatch settings installation related or account related?

Tags: overwatch

I have Overwatch installed on my personal PC. I'm playing it trough a friend's battlenet account. I'll soon buy a copy for myself and simply login in battlenet and play on the same installation on my PC. Will the settings I have for graphics, sensitivity and different heroes be saved for me, on the new account, or will they be saved on my friend's account and I'll get some default settings ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The settings are installation specific. They are stored in `C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Overwatch\Settings\Overwatch\` so your best bet would be to copy the files in that location from your friend's computer to the same location on yours.

Comment: Im playing on my pc with his acc, so we're all set to go. Thanks!

Comment: I actually missed that part, and thought you were asking if your settings were stored server-side! While the graphical settings (resolution etc.) are definitely per-PC, I am not completely sure that key bindings and such are not stored per-account. Other Blizzard games, like Heroes of the Storm, do keep some settings separate, so you may want to double-check.

Comment: If you look in the settings file, you can see that it's just graphics and sound settings, not things like mouse sensitivity or keybindings.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, **gameplay settings** like *sensitivity* and *keybindings* are account specific and loaded from the Blizzard servers when you login. You cannot copy them from an account to another, you have to re-setup everything by hand.

**Graphics settings** are installation specific and are located in `Documents/Overwatch/Settings/Overwatch`.